# Display an image over an iframe using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

i'm creating a loading Screen for a FiveM server, the thing is I want to display a cursor and FiveM doesn't allow that in the loading screen *(we can move the mouse, but the cursor is not showing)*. So in JS i've created a little script to display a cursor*(image)* depending on the mousemove event:

```js
window.onload = function()
{
  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event)
  {
    var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

    var x = event.clientX - cursor.width + 23;
    var y = event.clientY - 6;
    // console.log("x="+x+"  -  y="+y);

    $("#cursor").css({
        "left": x+"px",
        "top"     : y+"px"
    });
  });
}
```

My script works well, but not on iframe, the cause is that when the cursor is on the iframe, the JS script doesn't works anymore *(it doesn't apply the left/top position so the cursor stays outside of the iframe)*.

I tried modifying my css but in vain *(here it is, i think it will help):*

```css
#cursor
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999!important;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 40px;
}

iframe {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

My question is, is it possible to mouve an image hover the iframe *(and still being able to use the iframe)* ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to add to add position: absolute, also to the css of the cursor. I don't know if it run because i haven't tried it

Comment: your `cursor.width` is `undefined`

Comment: @tholeb change `cursor.width` to `cursor.getClientRects()[0].width` .. are you trying to listen for mouse event on iframe ??

Comment: @Poss The position class is working fine (I think).
And for me the cursor width is well defined, i got no problems, and no, i'm listening only onto the loading screen *(not in the iframe's website itsefl)*

Comment: Its probably because of security reasons similar in way  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624274/10794140

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, so, not possible I think. Thanks for your help.