# How to handle a multiple files response from a Ajax POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, zip

I'm using the [OGRE web client](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) to transform GeoJSON text data to ESRI shapefiles. To do it, I'm using a POST request with Ajax.

```
var data = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5] },
    "properties": { "prop0": "value0" }
  }]
};

function sendPost() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson',
        data: {json:JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: success
    });
}
```

The response from the POST request is multiple files (see image):[image]

How can I handle this kind of response ? I want to add the files to a ZIP file and download it. I think I can do it by using the [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) librairies. It should be something like that but I don't know how to handle the response:

```
function success(result) {
    console.log(result);

    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file = ("file1.shp", result[--file1 in the response--])

    var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});

    saveAs(content, "test.zip")
}
```

Need some help !! :)

**Edit:**
Trying with a XHR request, I can't seem to find how to correctly pass the JSON as text in the URL so that the URL works:

```
params = {
    json: JSON.stringify(data)
}

function formatParams( params ){
  return "?" + Object
        .keys(params)
        .map(function(key){
          return key+"="+params[key]
        })
        .join("&")
}

var url_long = "http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson";
var url = url_long + "?" + formatParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the result is already a zip file. If you just want to trigger the download, you just need FileSaver. The only thing you need is to get a *binary* content. Without further configuration, `$.ajax` will try decode the content as UTF8 and corrupt the content. Getting a Blob (or a Uint8Array) here is what you need.
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902299/using-jquery-ajax-to-download-a-binary-file), you may need to use a raw XHR request.

If you want to filter the content of the zip file, that won't be

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("file1.shp", result[--file1 in the response--])
```

but rather

```
var zip = new JSZip(result);
// keep file1, remove file2, etc
zip.remove("file2.shp")
```

Edit: here is how to POST the json with an XMLHttpRequest:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(data));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson");
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // ask for a binary result
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(evt) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var zip = new JSZip(xhr.response);
      console.log("success, got", Object.keys(zip.files));
    } else {
      console.log("http call error");
    }
  }
};

xhr.send(formData);
```

Which display `success, got Array [ "OGRGeoJSON.dbf", "OGRGeoJSON.prj", "OGRGeoJSON.shp", "OGRGeoJSON.shx" ]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you propose to pass the JSON text in the XHR ? I've been searching and can't find how to correctly pass the json so that the URL works. I edited the main post.

Comment: You can use `FormData` and `formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(data));` to send your json, I'll edit my answer with the code.