# How to use UTF-8 image data (png/jpeg/gif) from ajax call to render image to user?

Tags: javascript, image, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps where you can use a POST call to get image data (png/jpeg/gif).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map

Neither can I render the image to the user nor is it possible to download the file and display it when opened locally (the download works but the image file won't show an image).

This is the code that handles the image data from the POST request to the bing maps api:

```
// rsp contains UTF-8 image data (png)

let reader = new FileReader();
let file = new File([rsp], 'test.png');

// trying to render to user
reader.onloadend = function () {
    document.getElementById('img').src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + reader.result.substr(37); // substr(37) will get base 64 string in a quick and dirty way
};

reader.readAsDataURL(file);

// trying to make the image downloadable (just for testing purposes)

var a = document.createElement("a"),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.href = url;
a.text = "Test";
a.download = 'test.png';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: show in console what we getting in `src` ?  i think we have some syntax errors

Comment: to make your <a> tag a download link , assign `download` attribute to it .
also , have you tried to use `document.createElement("img")` and assigning src to it and then appending it ? it should work

Comment: @VadimHulevich console: data:image/png;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCgA...

Comment: @BrightFaith The download itself works, but the downloaded image file will not show an image.

Comment: i think because the encoding of images are not UTF-8 , for videos it's base64 , i am not sure about images , make sure if you are using correct encoding

Comment: I recommend you check answer here https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
must show you some image

Comment: @VadimHulevich Did it. It did not render a picture.

Comment: The api is definitely returning valid image data, as I get a preview in the browser developer console.

Comment: @JuliusS.  ok, try to put valid image source like a constant string, just for example;
image which https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter can render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a native XMLHttpRequest with responseType 'blob' or 'arraybuffer' to handle the binary server response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903375/6751513).

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", bingMapsPOSTEndpoint + '&' + queryParamsString, true);
    request.responseType = "blob";

    request.onload = function (e) {

        var dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
        document.getElementById('img').src = dataURL;

    };

    request.send();
```