# Error request pdf with ajax, XmpHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, xmlhttprequest, blob

i'm using ajax to make a request to an API, API makes a pdf a response with the file, but the ajax request return this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: XMLHttpRequest.responseText getter: responseText is only available if responseType is '' or 'text'.

this is the code:

`

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: "blob"
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            console.log("succuess")
            console.log(response)
            console.log(status)
            console.log(xhr)
            try {
                //ShowModalCargando(false);
                let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (elemento === null)
                    window.open(downloadUrl);
                else {
                    let iFrame = document.getElementById(elemento);
                    iFrame.src = downloadUrl;
                }

            } catch (ex) {
                ShowModalCargando(false);
                console.log(ex);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            ShowModalCargando(false);
            console.log("Error al intentar realizar la impresion: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
```

`

- i tried skip the `content-type`, did not work
- i tried to skip the `xhr response type`, and response with a empty
  pdf
- tried with a newest version of jquery and did not work (i'm using
  Jquery 1.11.3
- I test in chrome and mz and did'nt work
- Using postman works.

Comment: Does this answer your question:  [using jquery to download a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902299/using-jquery-ajax-to-download-a-binary-file)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using because xhrFields should work in jQuery 2.2+ I think

Comment: i solved it using `xmlhttprequest` instead `ajax`

Comment: You mean instead of `$.ajax` - xmlHTTPRequest is still "ajax"

Comment: right, that's what i mean, `xmlHTTPrequest` instead `$.ajax`, thanks guys